# Regular expression to match <font> attribute

Tags: c#, html, regex

I have a string which contains something like;

```
"<font color=\"Red\">"
```

I need a regular expression which will match on any color. I have tried the below regular expression with no luck.  Does anyone have some suggestions?

```
string pattern = "/<font[^>]*>/";
string newTag = Regex.Replace(txt_htmlBody.Text, pattern, "<font color=\"Black\">");
```

Comment: Note that using HtmlAgilityPack instead may save you huge amount of pain now/in future...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regular expressions in C# don't need pattern delimiters like PERL or PHP, so you need to change the pattern to:

```
string pattern = "<font[^>]*>";
                  ^         ^
            Notice the removed / from the expression
```

Comment: @clamchoda Please don't forget to accept the answer if it has solved your problem, Thank you.

Comment: my mistake, you answered so quickly and it wanted me to wait 5 mins - totally forgot!